# How to set different RTE Profile for different Sites in SXA

Tags: sxa, richtext-editor

I want to set different RTE profile for different Sites in SXA.

Is there a setting OR a other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this. The code that gets the profile doesn't seem to use any pipelines that you could hook into or anything that would allow tokens in that value.

```
  string queryString = WebUtil.GetQueryString("so", Settings.HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile);
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) queryString, "source");
  configurationResult = (EditorConfigurationResult) null;
  Database database = Context.Database;
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) database, "database");
  Sitecore.Data.Items.Item profile1 = database.GetItem(queryString);
```

Code above taken from `Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorPage.OnLoad()`

The only way to change that would be to replace the default RichText Editor form and change the underlying code. Then you could use tokens and something like `$site/path/to/htmlprofile`

Comment: Is this still the case?  I see in SXA 1.9, it uses `query:$xaRichTextProfile` as source for Rich Text fields. This would imply some logic around it.